# Send Exception to Cloud Foundry logging system with .Net app

Tags: c#, .net, cloud-foundry

I'm using Cloud Foundry and the clr build pack for .Net. All is going well except for an api call in my app that is throwing an exception. I can't find how to send log events to the Cloud Foundry Log System from .net.

I've tried a basic `Console.WriteLint(ex)`, but to no avail.

Any .Net CF users out there that have gotten the logging to work?

Comment: Which version of CloudFoundry with Windows support are you using? Unfortunately there have been multiple attempts to add Windows support, the original being http://www.ironfoundry.org/, but now there is a Pivotal-supported "Greenhouse" project built on top of the new Diego CF runtime.